# Prevent Client Queries from re-running after route changes

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I am new to ApolloClient/GQL but I understand it does well with caching to prevent multiple queries. I have a `<RootProvider />` in my app which when it mounts runs a query to get my list of accounts. Then the user selects their account, it 1) updates Global Redux provider, and 2) navigates to an account overview page. If i then "switch" my account (clear selectedAccount with `setSelectedAccountId('')`), the URL goes back to root and the query runs again. I have tried conditional query with `useLazyQuery` and i have tried `skip` option inside the `useQuery` itself, both without success. Skip itself will not even return cached data.

Is there a trick to making sure the data is cached between routes?

```
App Wrapper with Global Redux Store:

<Provider store={store}> //contains setSelectedAccountId action & selectedAccountId state
  <Router >
   <App /> 
  </Router >
</Provider>
```

App:

```
          <RootProvider
            setSelectedAccountId={setSelectedAccountId}
            selectedAccountId={selectedAccountId}
          >
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path={routes.root}>
                  <Root setSelectedAccountId={setSelectedAccountId} />
                </Route>
                 <Route exact path={routes.overview()}>
                    <OverviewProvider>
                      <Overview />
                    </OverviewProvider>
                  </Route>
              </Switch>
          </RootProvider>
```

RootProvider:

```
const RootProvider = ({
  children,
  selectedAccountId,
  setSelectedAccountId,
}: RootProviderProps): ReactElement => {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery<{ accounts: RootStateShape[] }>(GET_ACCOUNTS);

  const [selectedAccountDetails, setSelectedAccountDetails] = useState<RootStateShape | null>(null);


  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(error)}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <RootStateContext.Provider
      value={{ accounts: data?.accounts || [], selectedAccountDetails, setSelectedAccountDetails }}
    >
      {children}
    </RootStateContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And the `GET_ACCOUNTS` Query itself:

```
const GET_ACCOUNTS = gql`
  query getAccounts {
    accounts(accountType: "installers") @rest(type: "AccountsPayload", path: "/accounts?{args}") {
      accountId
      accountName
      isBillable
      recordType
      isActive
    }
  }
`;
```

I have tried to update the RootProvider to use `useLazyQuery` with a "mounted" state:

```
const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)
const [lazyLoadAccounts, { loading, error, data }] = useLazyQuery<{ accounts: RootStateShape[] }>(
    GET_ACCOUNTS
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted) {
      lazyLoadAccounts();
      setIsMounted(true);
    }
  }, [data, lazyLoadAccounts]);
```

I appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is to make a copy of the data that is returned.  That way I can use `skip` and still get a "copy" of the original data. I *hate* making a copy of stateful data like this, but it seems the only workaround?:

```
const RootProvider = (props: RootProviderProps): ReactElement => {
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(false);
  const [queryData, setQueryData] = useState<{ accounts: RootStateShape[] }>();
  const [selectedAccountDetails, setSelectedAccountDetails] = useState<RootStateShape | null>(null);

  const { loading, error } = useQuery<{ accounts: RootStateShape[] }>(GET_ACCOUNTS, {
    onCompleted: data => {
      setQueryData(data);
      setSkip(true);
    },
    skip,
  });

  if (loading) {
    return <Loading />;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(error)}</div>;
  }

  return (
    <RootStateContext.Provider
      value={{
        accounts: queryData?.accounts || [],
        selectedAccountDetails,
        setSelectedAccountDetails,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </RootStateContext.Provider>
```

Comment: looks like a hack but worked for me, thx